# Percent of total column after groupby

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Attempting to summarize a pandas dataframe and calculate a "percent of total" column on the result of a groupby of the original df.

Original df:

```
        Shape_Area                       LU
0  91254232.781776          Fallow Cropland
1    522096.071094  Mixed Wetland Hardwoods
2     87795.467187  Mixed Wetland Hardwoods
3       440.528367  Mixed Wetland Hardwoods
4    778952.154436         Dikes and Levees
```

Grouped result:

```
                              Shape_Area
LU                                      
Dikes and Levees           778952.154436
Fallow Cropland          91254232.781776
Mixed Wetland Hardwoods    610332.066649
```

I'd like to add an additional "PCT of Total" column for each LU type.  I'm not sure I'm accessing the groupby result correctly, probably not understanding what it is (a series?).

```
df = pd.DataFrame(narr, columns=['LU','Shape_Area'])
df = df.groupby(['LU'])[['Shape_Area']].sum()

#to print the example above after groupby
print df
```

Comment: I'm horrible at this forum UI, it's so darn foreign.  I think perhaps I should have just applied .reset_index() to the groupby and then I will be able to calculate a pct total column on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply calculate the sum of the `Shape_Area` series (which returns a scalar), and divide each row of `Shape_Area` in the grouped dataframe by this value.

```
grouped = df.groupby(['LU'])[['Shape_Area']].sum()
grouped['pct'] = grouped['Shape_Area'] / grouped['Shape_Area'].sum()
```

```
                           Shape_Area       pct
LU                                             
Dikes and Levees         7.789522e+05  0.008408
Fallow Cropland          9.125423e+07  0.985004
Mixed Wetland Hardwoods  6.103321e+05  0.006588
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for.  Thank you.  (cannot accept as answer for a few more mins.)